# Moving from Spring Boot 2/Zipkin/Sleuth to Spring Boot 3/Micrometer - equivalent of DefaultMessageSpanCustomizer

Tags: spring-boot, messaging, micrometer

I'm migrating a Spring Boot 2 + Sleuth/Zipkin app to Spring Boot 3 + Micrometer/Zipkin with Spring Cloud 2022.0.1.

I used to be able to add custom tags (sourced from message headers) to a span associated with any outgoing Message, by extending the `org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.messaging.DefaultMessageSpanCustomizer` class, overriding the `customizeHandle()` methods.

Is there an equivalent mechanism/hook provided by Spring Boot 3 / micrometer / Spring Cloud?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out in case anyone else needs this - register an `ObservationFilter` bean that checks if the context passed into `map()` is an instance of `RabbitMessageSenderContext` (I needed this for outbound AMQP messages).

In that case, the `context.getCarrier()` method returns the `org.springframework.amqp.core.Message`, and its then straightforward to map the headers to additional keys on the ObservationContext.